# Redirect Shopify Home To Password Page

Tags: redirect, passwords, shopify

I'm a WordPress guy with a client who wants to build the store part of his site in Shopify. He's password protecting it using Shopify's built-in password functionality.

I have the shop at the subdomain shop.clientdomain.com.

How do I get the password page to be the page that appears when someone goes to shop.clientdomain.com and not the home page? I've seen this store do it but I can't figure out how the redirect is set up:

https://blueprintnutrition.myshopify.com

If you go to that URL it redirects to the password page.

Thanks for any help you can offer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If password protection is turned on in the Shopify settings, that dialog asking for the password will just come up if the access to the home page is not authenticated. There really is nothing else to do but turn it on.

Are you saying the password protection setting is ON but you can see the homepage without providing a password?

Comment: Okay, I thought Shopify was replicating a non-signed experience but because I was signed in as Admin is was letting me see the page. Using an incognito browser worked as expected. Reading your comment helped me realize my mistake. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to activate password protected page in shopify so follow these step go to **Online Store > preferences >** find **Password protection** > 
**Enable password** and set your password and you can leave message for visitors.